# yum gets stuck at Running Transaction

Tags: yum

We have an RPM created from a TGZ which includes a set of files to be installed at /usr/glassfish. For some reason, yum gets stuck while Running Transaction (stuck for hours, doesn't continue...). Tried to attach a screenshot but serverfault won't let me.

Any idea why?

Comment: "Any idea why?" refers to the yum problem, not the fact serverfault won't let me add an image.

Comment: What happens when you install the package by hand?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who gets stuck with this issue - I came across this problem and it was because I killed yum, which in turn left a lock file for `rpm` in the open.

In which case, you'll need to run `rm /var/lib/rpm/.rpm.lock`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use `strace` to have a look at what yum is actually doing. Maybe it could also help to do a `yum clean all`, you might need to run `yum-complete-transaction` afterwards.

Also just installing the RPM with `rpm -Uvh your-rpm-file.rpm` might give you more insight.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too and it was caused by a broken NFS mount. After unmounting it with `umount -l <mount_point>` yum started to work again.